# Including allennlp predictor arguments in config.json

Tags: prediction, allennlp

I'm training an allennlp crf_tagger. I'm using a predictor which is based on the
[SentenceTaggerPredictor](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/39c40fe38cd2fd36b3465b0b3c031f54ec824160/allennlp/predictors/sentence_tagger.py#L26). The issue is the tokenizer argument - in the case of the SentenceTaggerPredictor there's a language argument.

Since SentenceTaggerPredictor has language="en_core_web_sm" as a defauly argument, when I do

```
Predictor.from_path("model.tar.gz", "sentence_tagger")
```

The tokenizer is created using the default language. But what happens if the training data was tokenized using a different language. How do I specify the arguments for the predictor in the model `config.json` such that `Predictor.from_path` will be constructed using a non-default language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Predictor.from_path()` method has an `overrides` parameter that you could use in this case. For example, `Predictor.from_path("model.tar.gz", "sentence_tagger", overrides={"dataset_reader.tokenizer.language": "en"})`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to  work, the overrides only modify the config.json which is used to construct the model and tokenizer as you show. But the language is an argument of the Predictor itself. and Predictor.from_path always constructs the predictor using default arguments. There's a github issue which I've added my feedback to. I know how to load the archive and create the predictor from that but I would prefer to be able to specify additional predictor args at model training time (via config.json) and it appears thats not currently supported.

Comment: Oh I see. Okay I've made a PR to address this: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/pull/5275

Comment: Thanks, ideally instead of passing kwargs to Predictor.from_path it would be nice if you could store them in config json even though they're not actually required for training (i.e. in this specific case the data loader requires the input text is already tokenised but the predictor doesn't). But kwargs on Predictor.from_path is a good step forward.